# Why javascript callbacks are asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Why Javascript callbacks are asynchronous and how it works into the javascript engine ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow, because it is *not* about a specific programming problem.

Comment: The callbacks are asynchronous because the v8 engine has different queues for the callbacks and the web APIs while it has a call stack for the functions, so when you call a function that has a callback, that callback is pushed to callback queue and then the event loop will wait for the call stack to be empty and will then push the callbacks from the call back queue back to the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why Javascript callbacks are asynchronous

They don't have to be, but if the function that accepts a callback isn't asynchronous then you might as well just get the data using a return value instead.

> and how it works into the javascript engine ?

Usually by binding an event listener.

Comment: Ok thanks to you. But how write an asynchronous javascript function so ...?

Comment: +1 My coworkers always get this wrong, and then they get all confused. There's **no** magic when passing a function as a callback that makes it async. Code is only asynchronous when calling an asynchronous API (i.e. IO functions like an HTTP request).

Comment: @ThomasPons — You could do something with `setInterval`… but, in general, the times when having a function be asynchronous are when it interacts with something outside the JS engine (like HTTP).

Comment: I understand :). And a last little question, so node.js is async because it uses IO (thread pool wrint in C/C++) right ?

Comment: @ThomasPons - nodejs is async because when you make a call to IO, the function immediately returns instead of doing the IO first. It could still be async without a thread-pool, as long as it doesn't interrupt the current execution context. It uses a thread-pool to be efficient, not to be async. Async can be accomplished with a simple event-loop such as libev running in a single thread.

Comment: "if the function that accepts a callback isn't asynchronous then you might as well just get the data using a return value instead" - No. Think about `Array.forEach()` e.g.